# Can critical points occur at endpoints? E.g. $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ at the interval $[1,4]$

Tags: calculus, maxima-minima

Given that an extreme value can only occur at a critical point and in the following case $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x} \quad [1,4]$$ we definitely have two absolute extreme values (maximum and minimum), are $x = 1$ and $x = 4$ critical points?

If so, what is the reasoning for that: the fact that they are in the domain of $f$ and they are not differentiable at those points?

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: It's just a matter of definition.

Comment: @KennyLau not sure what you mean here.

Comment: There is not much mathematical value in the question "can critical points occur at endpoints" because it is merely a matter of definition.

Comment: Critical points are usually defined as points where the first derivative vanishes, so no end points can be critical points (as there is no derivative). But you can always talk about *extrema end points*.

Comment: Some texts may define "critical point" as point where the derivative is zero.  Then to find the maximum you check the critical points and the endpoints.  Other texts may define "critical point" as point where the derivative is zero or an endpoint.  Then to find the maximum you check the critical points.

Comment: @KennyLau I see your point but, shouldn't the definition be the same all across the context (or across every Calc book)? For example: critical points being a point in the domain of a function where f' = 0 or f' not existing.

Comment: Definition the same in every book?  That may be a good idea, but not likely to be implemented in our lifetime.

Comment: @GEdgar hahah I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [critical point](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics)) is a point at which the derivative vanishes. So definitely, $1$ and $4$ are not critical points.

Now those points are at the boundary of the domain of $f$ and are extremas.

However, consider a point $x$ which is a minimum or a maximum of a differentiable function $f$ and which belongs to the interior of the the domain of $f$. Then $f^\prime(x)=0$.

**In summary**

An extrema belonging to the interior of the domain of a differentiable map is a critical point.

An extrema may not be a critical point, if it belongs to the frontier of the domain. Example: the function of the question.

And obviously the derivative of a function can vanish at a point belonging to the frontier. In that case the point is a critical point.

Lastly a critical point may not be an extrema. Example $f: x \mapsto x^3$ at $x=0$.

Comment: That was very helpful my friend, I appreciate your answer. Have a great day!

Comment: One question though: so the sentence "extreme values can only occur at critical points" is incorrect. Agreed?

Comment: You’re right. Enjoy too day, night or whatever it is where you’re.

Comment: Ok got it. Thank you.

Comment: This is quite late, but would you mind taking a look at https://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage7/Lesson/critical.html, in which the instructor suggests the endpoint(s) of an interval inside the domain is a boundary point.  That would contradict the 2nd paragraph of your summary.

Comment: @GNUSupporter At the end this is a question of definition. Wikipedia doesn't include interval endpoints as critical points.

Comment: At the *current* version of Wikipedia, the definition for the single variable case is "a point in the domain of the function where the function is either **not differentiable** or the derivative is equal to zero."  Please see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3194859/290189) for a discussion about the *non*-differentiability of $f$ at endpoints of the domain.  The comments under that answer provided a link to [Wiki's page on differentiable functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function), in which $f$ is difined on *open* sets.

Comment: We have *another* term called [left/right differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability) for the one-sided derivatives at the endpoints of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I want to point out that it is not sure that you have an extreme point in the critical points. One example is $f(x)=x^3$ which has a $x=0$ as critical point but obviously it's not an extreme.

When we are trying to find a critical point in a certain domain we set $f'(x)=0$. Then (for the fact that I mentioned that not every critical point is extreme) we plug those critical points and the endpoints of the given domain(in case this domain has endpoints)in the function and see which of them is the smaller value(minimum) and which the bigger(maximum). You realise that altough the endpoints may not be critical points, they can behave as extreme points. That happens to the function you mention.